# Using a named range in autofilter Field

Tags: excel, vba

I use autofilter for a bunch of things from corporate reports. However, every now and then corporate changes the fields around which messes up my macros. If I am able to use named ranges instead of column numbers in the autofilter code I can fix really easy by just changing the column referenced in the name range.

```
Sheets("Current Pipeline").Range("$A$1:$AI$150000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=LC
```

I haven't been able to find a way to do it, any thoughts?

Comment: A possibly better alternative would be to determine the column by using its header (title). If the header e.g. is `"MyField"`, then you could use `Dim cIndex As Long: cIndex = Application.Match("MyField", Sheets("Current Pipeline").Range("A1:AI1"),0)`, and you could auto filter with `... Field:=cIndex, ...`. This will of course fail if someone renames the header.

Comment: `Criteria1:=Range("LC")` if your named range is called "LC"

Comment: This worked, but I don't see how to mark your answer as the correct answer. Thank you very much, I am going to use this technique on many more things :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your named range is called "LC" then you'd use:

```
 Sheets("Current Pipeline").Range("$A$1:$AI$150000").AutoFilter _
               Field:=4, Criteria1:=Range("LC")
```